# migrate sqlserver function into postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, function

I have a function in the SQL server that calculates the due amount.
I have migrated my database into Postgres but I can't use that function in Postgres because both databases have different schema and syntax.
I am new to Postgres and I don't know how to migrate that function in Postgres from the SQL server.
here is the function, please help me to convert this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION "CalcDue"(
    "@duedate" datetime,
    "@latefee" decimal,
    "@limit" decimal
)
RETURNS decimal
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
begin

DECLARE @days int
DECLARE @TotalLateFee decimal
SET @days = DateDiff(DAY,@duedate,DATEADD(MINUTE,330,GETUTCDATE()))
if @days < 0 set @days = 0
SET @TotalLateFee = @days * @latefee

  if @TotalLateFee > @limit
    return @limit
    else return @TotalLateFee
  return isnull(@TotalLateFee,0)
end
```

Thank you  !!

Comment: What exactly does `DateDiff(DAY,@duedate,DATEADD(MINUTE,330,GETUTCDATE()))` do?

Comment: DateDiff() find a difference of day

Comment: @duedate - (date.now +5 hour) is something like this

Comment: `days` is an integer. What if the difference between `duedate` and now + 5 hours is `4 days 23 hours and 20 minutes`? Should that then be just 4 days? Or round it to 5 days?

Comment: @duedate is parameter in the function

Comment: The DateDiff finds a day

Comment: I understand that, but if the real result of the difference is `4 days 23 hours and 20 minutes` then what should `days` evaluate to? 4 days or rounded to 5 days? What about a result like `0 days 18 hours 42 minutes`?

Comment: No, it can't happen because I'm storing date in format of Indian Standard Timezone

Comment: So `duedate` is in reality **only** a date without a time? But even if that is the case, you can still get a result with days, hours and minutes, e.g. `date '2021-07-28' - (current_timestamp + interval '5 hours')` returns `62 days 7 hours 27 mins`

Comment: No there is time also. that's why I do addition 330 minutes to the date (because it gets UTC date). and I want a date in IST for finding the exact days.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232931/discussion-between-bhavin-varsur-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 0):

It's totally unclear how fractional "days" should be treated in the calculation. But a naive implementation in Postgres could look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION calc_due(p_duedate timestamp, p_late_fee decimal, p_limit decimal)
  RETURNS decimal
as
$$
declare
  l_days int;
  l_total_late_fee decimal;  
begin
  l_days := extract(day from p_duedate - (current_timestamp + interval '5 hours'));
  if l_days < 0 then 
     l_days := 0;
  end if;
  l_total_late_fee := l_days * p_late_feed;
  return least(p_limit, l_total_late_fee);
end;
$$
immutable
language plpgsql;
```

Or a bit shorter as a SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION calc_due(p_duedate timestamp, p_late_fee decimal, p_limit decimal)
  RETURNS decimal
as
$$
  select least(p_limit, greatest(0, extract(day from p_duedate - current_timestamp + interval '5 hours')) * p_late_fee);
$$
immutable
language sql;
```

Comment: I tried both of them but I got error about '$$'.

Comment: ERROR:  unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$
declare
  l_days int"